# what is the difference between jquery-latest.min.js and jquery 2.1.1?which is better?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I included both the versions and also the jquery-ui to my jsp.
It messes up the functionalities of my jsp. Any suggestions.

Comment: include only one jquery file preferably newer version jquery minified file(having `.min` in the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that `jquery-latest.min.js` is always the latest version and `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` is a specific version.

The difference between `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` and `jquery-2.1.1.js` is that in the `min` version all unnecessary characters from source code are removed without changing its functionality. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming).

In many cases the best option would be to use the `jquery-latest.min.js` version. Only one of them shall be included, not both.